# Implement Regular expression in android

Tags: android, regex

I got stuck in this regular expression as I am having a string as:

```
   String str = "/abcde/samplename.xyz"
```

I want to replace this samplename.xyz from a new string, so how can I apply the regular expression in this ?

Comment: would you like to only remove samplename.xyz and result will be /abcde/?

Comment: yes with /abcde/ I will append another string value after replacing samplename.xyz

Comment: please see my answer and other two, all the answer now correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String startString=str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```

Comment: Yes you right man, I have also done the same thing. +1 for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out.....

```
    String str = "/abcde/samplename.xyz";

    String req=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

now you get the value of: ***req=samplename.xyz*** and you can replace with which ever string value you want

```
    String rep=str.replace(req, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 String str = "/abcde/samplename.xyz";
    String str1 = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("strArr[1]=", "" + str1);
```

check this.i hope its useful to you.

Comment: no, it will split from the the first backslash..I want it to split from the last backslash

Comment: but it will only give abcde , but he needs /abcde/

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
String str = "/abcde/samplename.xyz";
        String result=str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        Log.d("Hello","Result="+result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 String[] result = str.split("/");

 String LastItem = result[str.length -1];

 LastItem.replace(newString);
```